# Xcode use of unresolved Identifier error

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am new to Xcode so I didn't get how to resolve this error by reading other articles in StackOverflow related to this. Basically I am working on the CoreData part and the following code accesses Amount, Bank Name and Title field but it's giving this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four lines in your code are *outside* any context. You can't do that. No executable code can appear except inside a function — usually, some method of some class.

So those four lines need to be *inside* the ViewController class, not before it, and again, not just loose inside it, but in some *method* of the ViewController class.

Comment: Thanks Matt, placed those lines inside UIViewController and that fixed those 2 errors.